# Проблема с выписыванием альтернативного ответа

Tags: c++, вектор, файловый-ввод-вывод

Есть код, задача: я задаю начальную букву, программа выводит слово с этой буквой и его значение. Вот и проблема в том, что если такового слова с буквой нет, то должно выйти предупреждение, но я не знаю как его вывести. Так как работаю с векторами и если получается вывести это предупреждение, то оно будет равно количеству строк в файле, а мне нужно всего один раз. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
for(auto &element: cont){
                    if(element.definition.length() && *element.definition.begin() == letter){ //если есть слово с такой буквой
                        std::cout << element.definition << " - " << trim(element.discription) << std::endl;
                        output << element.definition << " - " << trim(element.discription) << std::endl;
                        output.close();
                    }else if(element.definition.length() && *element.definition.begin() != letter){ //если слова нет с такой буквой
                    std::cout << "Нет слова с такой буквой в начале" << std::endl;
                    }
}
```

Comment: Делай флаг нахождения или правильно юзни find

Comment: @Assaraid, Вам не кажется, что в вашем вопросе не хватает информации для получения  полноценного ответа?..Постарайтесь вопрос формулировать более грамотно, потому что и вопрос и ответ могут помочь и другим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый хороший способ - использовать [std::find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). Так как информации о типах в приведенном коде не хватает, пишу приблизительно. Но тут нужно немножко постараться. Возможно, нужно будет поправить чуточку. Element_t - это так я назвал тип, который имеет элемент cont.

```
auto it = std::find_if(cont.begin(), cont.end(), [letter](const Element_t& element) {
// тут нужно написать правильное условие, которое будет проверять наш element
  return !element.definition.empty() && element.definition[0] == letter
});
if (it == cont.end()) {
    std::cout << "ой, ничего не нашли";
} else {
  std::cout << it->definition << " - " << trim(it->discription) << std::endl;
}
```

вот это - `element.definition.length()` - очень плохой вариант. есть же `empty()` - и очевиднее, и красивее

Я также случайно потерял вывод в output, но думаю, это легко допишите сами.

Но если нужно найти все варианты, то можно где то так

```
auto condition = [letter](const Element_t& element) {
// тут нужно написать правильное условие, которое будет проверять наш element
  return !element.definition.empty() && element.definition[0] == letter
};
 auto it = std::find_if(cont.begin(), cont.end(), condition );
if (it == cont.end()) {
    std::cout << "ой, ничего не нашли";
} else {
  for (;it != cond.end(); it = std::find_if(++it, cont.end(), condition );) {
    std::cout << it->definition << " - " << trim(it->discription) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Вот только такая проблемка, я пишу букву "n" к примеру, в файле находятся как минимум 2 слова таких, но выписывает лишь одно. А в чем проблема не могу допереть

Comment: Об этом в условии задачи ничего не было сказано

Comment: Кстати, покопался и решил с твоим примером. Огромное спасибо, за помощь теперь выводится все как нужно.